# Xcode 10: iOS Team Provisioning Profile doesn't support the $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)* Pass Type ID

Tags: ios, passkit, xcode10, ios12

I'm unable to build my project in Xcode 10. Getting following error:

> Xcode 10: iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxx.xxx" doesn't support the $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)* Pass Type ID.

The same identifier works for older Xcode versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug of Xcode10.

My workaround is edit entitlements file: replace `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)*` with value of `com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers` in you `Team Provisioning Profile`